# Need redirect my gateway to a enpoint (bad request)

Tags: express-gateway

well I need create a endpoint where can create a user, using express-gateway, in this have 2 ports running.

1. gateway http server listening on :::8181
2. admin http server listening on 127.0.0.1:9876

I can create a user sending my information to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:9876/users
```

I can't use this how my end point because have other configuration on my frontend, so in my frontend send my information for create user to:

```
http://localhost:8181/api/user/create
```

Now I need send my information to this `http://localhost:8181/api/user/create` and redirect internal in the gateway to this `http://127.0.0.1:9876/users`, I try something but just have bad gateway or not found. I call this end point users, so this is the script.

```
http:
  port: 8181
admin:
  port: 9876
  host: localhost
apiEndpoints:
  events:
    host: localhost
    paths: ["/api/events*", "/swagger*"]
    methods: ["GET", "PATCH"]
  users:
    host: localhost
    paths: "/api/user/create*"
    url: "http://localhost:9876"
    methods: ["POST", "OPTIONS"]
  eventsCreate:
    host: localhost
    paths: "/api/events*"
    methods: ["POST", "PUT", "OPTIONS"]
  auth:
    host: localhost
    paths: "/api/auth*"
    methods: ["POST", "GET", "OPTIONS"]
serviceEndpoints:
  auth:
    url: "http://localhost:59868"
  events:
    url: "http://localhost:5000"
  users:
    url: "http://localhost:9876"
policies:
  - basic-auth
  - cors
  - expression
  - key-auth
  - log
  - oauth2
  - proxy
  - rate-limit
  - jwt
  - request-transformer
pipelines:
  authPipeline:
    apiEndpoints:
      - auth
    policies:
      - cors:
      - log:
          action:
            message: "auth ${req.method}"
      - proxy:
          action:
            serviceEndpoint: auth
            changeOrigin: true
  eventsPipeline:
    apiEndpoints:
      - events
    policies:
      - cors:
      - log:
          action:
            message: "events ${req.method}"
      - proxy:
          action:
            serviceEndpoint: events
            changeOrigin: true
  usersPipeline:
    apiEndpoints:
      - users
    policies:
      - cors:
      - log:
          action:
            message: "users ${req.method}"
      - proxy:
          action:
            serviceEndpoint: users
            changeOrigin: true
  userPipeline:
    apiEndpoints:
      - events
    policies:
      - cors:
      - log:
          action:
            message: "events ${req.method}"
      - proxy:
          action:
            serviceEndpoint: events
            changeOrigin: true
  eventsCreatePipeline:
    apiEndpoints:
      - eventsCreate
    policies:
      - cors:
      - log:
          action:
            message: "events ${req.method}"
      - jwt:
          action:
            secretOrPublicKey: "MORTADELAIsMyPassion321"
            checkCredentialExistence: false
      - proxy:
          action:
            serviceEndpoint: events
            changeOrigin: true
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to map the incoming URL `http://localhost:8181/api/user/create` to the Express Gateway administration URL `http://localhost:9876/users`, but your proxy policy only changes the hostname and port components of the URL, not the path.

This is described in the [Path Management section of the Proxy documentation](https://www.express-gateway.io/docs/policies/proxy/#path-management).
To change the path, you'll need to either adjust the existing `users` service endpoint or create a new one, and add some instructions to the proxy middleware configuration:

For example, add a new ServiceEndpoint called `userCreate`:

```yaml
serviceEndpoints:
  auth:
    url: "http://localhost:59868"
  userCreate:
    url: "http://localhost:9876/users"
  users:
    url: "http://localhost:9876"
```

And then refer to the new service endpoint and set stripPath in the proxy configuration:

```yaml
      - proxy:
         action:
            serviceEndpoint: userCreate
            changeOrigin: true
            stripPath: true
```